# Automate, "Enable USB Debugging" using any tool on Android Lollipop

Tags: android, automation

We are trying to automate a scenario on android Lollipop version. As part of the scenario we need to automate enabling of USB Debugging mode.

Comment: Please edit your question and explain in greater detail what this "scenario" is. Enabling USB debugging has major security ramifications, which is why Android apps cannot enable it programmatically.

Comment: The scenario starts with "Enabling USB Debugging" and automating web application on native browser. So I wanted any automation tool which can work with out enabling of USB Debugging.